# Will there be a 4th 'Zones of Thought' book?

Tags: vernor-vinge, zones-of-thought

Is there any word on a sequel to Vernor Vinge's [*Children of the Sky*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1285509) (the 3rd in the [*Zones of Thought*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?11587) books)?

It seems to be ends as if there will be another book, but a cursory Internet search has not given me any answers.

If there is any information about possible sequel at this point I would love to know?

Answer (score 12):

I just did a quick scan and didn't see any commitments to schedule, but I did find a statement of (possible) intent from 2013:

> Do you have any plans for Zones novels after “The Children in the Sky”?
>
> **VV**: I have an events trajectory that probably needs two or three more novels to complete.
>
> <sub>[Source](http://scifiportal.eu/interview-with-vernor-vinge/)</sub>

For a better answer, I suggest websearching for more recent interviews... or catch up with him at an SF convention; he's a very approachable guy, in my experience.